# Javascript remove leading and trailing spaces from multiline string and replace the rest of whitespace chunks with commas

Tags: javascript, json, regex, csv

How can I convert this text

```
data=`ID   ra      dec     V       VR      MJD
  100     30.1  +15     7.00    -10     2450000.1234
200   30.2      +16     12.226  -5.124  2450000.2345
   300  30.3     +17    13.022  12.777    2450000.3456


400      30.4  +18     14.880  13.666  2450000.6789
500 30.5        +19 12.892      -1.835  2450001
 600     30.6    +20     17.587  15.340  2450002.123
700     30.7    +21       13.984  13.903  2450000.123456 
800    30.8    +22     20.00   10.000  2450003.0     `
```

i.e an imported text with multiple lines and columns separated by spaces and tabs, into this

```
ID,ra,dec,V,VR,MJD
100,30.1,+15,7.00,-10,2450000.1234
200,30.2,+16,12.226,-5.124,2450000.2345
300,30.3,+17,13.022,12.777,2450000.3456


400,30.4,+18,14.880,13.666,2450000.6789
500,30.5,+19,12.892,-1.835,2450001
600,30.6,+20,17.587,15.340,2450002.123
700,30.7,+21,13.984,13.903,2450000.123456
800,30.8,+22,20.00,10.000,2450003.0
```

Unfortunately,

- this regex `data=data.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'').replace(/[\t \r]+/g,',');` only works with the first line,
- this one `data.replace(/[^\S\r\n]+$/gm, "").replace(/[\t \r]+/g,',');`
  is ok, but only for for for traling.

**Extra:** How can I transform it to a `json` which separate the two blocks into two datasets such as `[[{id:..., ra:...},{},{}],[{id:..., ra:...},{},{}]]`

Comment: are there spaces between the values or tabs?

Comment: Thank you for your quick comment. They can be one or multiple spaces or tabs.

Comment: do they have the same meaning (as separating)? what is with sparsed values?

Comment: no, they are just a way to separate data columns

Comment: Your 'Extra' is a separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string conversion might be easier with split/join and trim:

```
data
    .split(/\r?\n/)
    .map(row => row.trim().split(/\s+/).join(','))
    .join('\n')
```

The extra credit is a little more involved. :)

```
const rows = data.split(/\r?\n/).map(row => row.trim().split(/\s+/).join(','));
const keys = rows.shift().split(',');
const chunks = rows.join("\n").split(/\n{2,}/);

const output = chunks .map(chunk => chunk.split("\n").map(
    row => row.split(',').reduce((obj, v, i) => {
        obj[keys[i]] = v;
        return obj;
    }, {})
));
```

Comment: I wouldn't rely on ES6, browser support is not the best.

Comment: Good point.  This wouldn't be a good solution for use in the browser without transpilation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This method lets trailing spaces `"800,30.8,+22,20.00,10.000,2450003.0", "", "", "", "", ""` which lead to "misplaced" key:values and then to strange output arrays `[Array[4], Array[5], Array[1], Array[2]]`

Comment: I should have made `chunks` by splitting on _three_ newlines, not two.  Updated.

Comment: Easy enough to convert to ES5 though, e.g. `.map(function(row){ return row.trim().split(/\s+/).join(','); })`

Comment: Now it fills per column: `[Array[4], Array[4], Array[3]]` →`Array[4] ` → `Object(0)` → `[ID:"2450000.1234", MJD :"2450000.1234",V :"2450000.1234",VR: "2450000.1234"]`

Comment: Hmm... that's not what I'm seeing.  Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oq659bc5/) with output to the console.

Comment: In that jfiddle, it outputs an `array[2]` containing `[array[3] ,array[5]]`, each element containing the same `[ID:"2450000.1234", MJD :"2450000.1234" ....]` . Very curious. Does it depend from the browser? *Chromium 50.0.2661.102 Ubuntu 14.04*

Comment: Oh, I see!  No, my solution was just wrong.  Sorry about that.  I've updated.  Here's a new [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nzLzoxsv/).

Comment: This works! Can it be generalized for an arbitrairly number of `\n\n\n\n\n\n`?

Comment: Yep, just change the `chunk` split to: `/\n{2,}/`. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nzLzoxsv/1/).

Comment: Uhm, no, it produces an `array[12]` also containing empty lines

Comment: Perhaps a typo?  If you look at the latest [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nzLzoxsv/2/) it should produce an `array[2]`.

Comment: Sorry, I was using the code above instead of the one in the jfiddle. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3):

You're nearly there. You want the multiline flag on the first replace,
but don't replace `\n`, so don't use `\s`. Use `[ \t]` instead:

```js
var data = 'ID   ra      dec     V       VR      MJD\n' +
        '  100     30.1  +15     7.00    -10     2450000.1234\n' +
        '200   30.2      +16     12.226  -5.124  2450000.2345\n' +
        '   300  30.3     +17    13.022  12.777    2450000.3456\n' +
        '\n' +
        '\n' +
        '400      30.4  +18     14.880  13.666  2450000.6789\n' +
        '500 30.5        +19 12.892      -1.835  2450001\n' +
        ' 600     30.6    +20     17.587  15.340  2450002.123\n' +
        '700     30.7    +21       13.984  13.903  2450000.123456\n' +
        '800    30.8    +22     20.00   10.000  2450003.0     \n'

var result = data.replace(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/gm,'').replace(/[ \t]+/g,',')
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
// First: the trimming part. Split on newlines, process
// each line by trimming it and replacing remaining white
// space with commas
var data = 'ID   ra      dec     V       VR      MJD\n\
  100     30.1  +15     7.00    -10     2450000.1234\n\
200   30.2      +16     12.226  -5.124  2450000.2345\n\
   300  30.3     +17    13.022  12.777    2450000.3456\n\
\n\
\n\
400      30.4  +18     14.880  13.666  2450000.6789\n\
500 30.5        +19 12.892      -1.835  2450001\n\
 600     30.6    +20     17.587  15.340  2450002.123\n\
700     30.7    +21       13.984  13.903  2450000.123456 \n\
800    30.8    +22     20.00   10.000  2450003.0     ';

data = data.split('\n');
var i = 0, l = data.length;
for ( ; i < l; i++)
    data[i] = data[i].trim().replace(/\s+/g,',');
data = data.join('\n');
document.write('<h1>Formatted data string</h1><pre><code>'+data+'</code></pre>');

// Now to turn it into objects.
// We'll strip the first line because
// that'll be the list of column names:
var cols = data.replace(/^([^\n]+)\n/,'$1').split(','),
    columnCount = cols.length;
data = data.replace(/^[^\n]+\n/,'');

// Now separate the 2 datasets
var datasets = data.split('\n\n\n');
document.write('<h1>First dataset</h1><pre><code>'+datasets[0]+'</code></pre>');
document.write('<h1>Second dataset</h1><pre><code>'+datasets[1]+'</code></pre>')

// Now we go through each line and
// place the values into objects which
// we'll push to an array
var processed = [];
i = 0;
l = datasets.length;
for ( ; i < l; i++){
    processed[i] = [];
    var lines = datasets[i].split('\n'),
        lineCount = lines.length;
    for (var j = 0; j < lineCount; j++){
        var dataArray = lines [j].split(','),
            obj = {};
        for (var k = 0; k < columnCount; k++)
            obj[cols[k]] = dataArray[k];
        processed[i].push(obj);
    }
}
var finalJSON = JSON.stringify(processed);
document.write('<h1>Final JSON</h1><pre><code>'+finalJSON+'</code></pre>');
```

Comment: This is a very complete answer. Very strangely, the `console.log(JSON.stringify(processed))`  returns the correct result, while `console.log(processed)` returns an array of 3 and an array of 5, each one with strange key:values such as
`undefined : "2450000.3456↵↵↵400"`

Answer (score 1):

So, since you know the exact format of each line, you can use capture groups on a per-line basis to extract the details. Try something like this:

`/^\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*$/mg`

Remember that `\s` matches all whitespace, while `\S` matches non-whitespace. You may need to tweak the capture groups to your liking, if necessary. Then, using the multiline and global flags, we are all set up to iterate over all the matches.

Here's the code:

```
// Your data, with the header removed, formatted as a string literal:
var data = "100     30.1  +15     7.00    -10     2450000.1234\n"+
"200   30.2      +16     12.226  -5.124  2450000.2345\n"+
"   300  30.3     +17    13.022  12.777    2450000.3456\n"+
"\n"+
"\n"+
"400      30.4  +18     14.880  13.666  2450000.6789\n"+
"500 30.5        +19 12.892      -1.835  2450001\n"+
" 600     30.6    +20     17.587  15.340  2450002.123\n"+
"700     30.7    +21       13.984  13.903  2450000.123456 \n"+
"800    30.8    +22     20.00   10.000  2450003.0";

// The pattern to grab the data:
var data_pattern = /^\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*$/mg;

// Keep matching until we run out of lines that match...
var results = [];
var line_match;
while ((line_match = data_pattern.exec(data)) !== null){
    // Parse the match into a json object and add it to the results.
    results.push({
        ID: line_match[1],
        ra: line_match[2],
        dec: line_match[3],
        V: line_match[4],
        VR: line_match[5],
        MJD: line_match[6]
    });
}

// Output the results.
console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
```

And here's the results on the console:

```
[
  {
    "ID": "100",
    "ra": "30.1",
    "dec": "+15",
    "V": "7.00",
    "VR": "-10",
    "MJD": "2450000.1234"
  },
  {
    "ID": "200",
    "ra": "30.2",
    "dec": "+16",
    "V": "12.226",
    "VR": "-5.124",
    "MJD": "2450000.2345"
  },
  {
    "ID": "300",
    "ra": "30.3",
    "dec": "+17",
    "V": "13.022",
    "VR": "12.777",
    "MJD": "2450000.3456"
  },
  {
    "ID": "400",
    "ra": "30.4",
    "dec": "+18",
    "V": "14.880",
    "VR": "13.666",
    "MJD": "2450000.6789"
  },
  {
    "ID": "500",
    "ra": "30.5",
    "dec": "+19",
    "V": "12.892",
    "VR": "-1.835",
    "MJD": "2450001"
  },
  {
    "ID": "600",
    "ra": "30.6",
    "dec": "+20",
    "V": "17.587",
    "VR": "15.340",
    "MJD": "2450002.123"
  },
  {
    "ID": "700",
    "ra": "30.7",
    "dec": "+21",
    "V": "13.984",
    "VR": "13.903",
    "MJD": "2450000.123456"
  },
  {
    "ID": "800",
    "ra": "30.8",
    "dec": "+22",
    "V": "20.00",
    "VR": "10.000",
    "MJD": "2450003.0"
  }
]
```

I hope this helped.